# Why does my rolling adler32 checksum not work in go? (modulo arithmetic)

Tags: go, modulo, checksum, adler32

I am implementing, in go, a [rolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) version of the [adler32 checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20086159/628786) was helpful to double check my maths. However I am struggling at implementing it correctly in golang.

I wrote the following code:

```golang
func roll(adler, n, leave, enter uint32) uint32 {
    a := adler & 0xffff
    b := adler >> 16

    a = (a + enter - leave) % MOD
    b = (b - n*leave - 1 + a) % MOD
    return b<<16 | a
}
```

It tested it on various inputs and it worked fine, until I decided to run it on random data. Here is a [sample](https://play.golang.org/p/VxRqoLcFQr) where it does not work (I found several of them).

What is baffling me is that the same code in python works perfectly on those inputs:

```py
def roll(adler, n, leave, enter):
    a = adler & 0xffff
    b = adler >> 16

    a = (a + enter - leave) % MOD
    b = (b - n*leave - 1 + a) % MOD
    return b<<16 | a
```

For good measure, I am including [proof](https://repl.it/EhAV/0) that this works in python. Note that the python checksum matches the non-rolling version of the go checksum (and that part is directly from the go core libraries).

I studied my results on all the other problematic samples, and found that I am never making a mistake on the least significant bits of the checksum (the "a" bits). Also, the error is consistently the same, equals to `0xe10000`. I suspect a peculiarity of how go handles modulo operations on uint32 integers to be the cause of this.

What is happening and how do I fix my code?

Comment: Your subtraction is wrapping around.

Comment: How would you fix the code?

Comment: You get the same discrepancy (0xe10000) in the Python code if you apply a 32 bit mask in the calculation of b like this: `b = ((b - (n*leave) - 1 + a) & 0xffffffff) % MOD`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integers in Python are signed. You declared all the integers in the golang version to be unsigned. That's the difference.

When an unsigned number is subtracted from a smaller unsigned number, you get a huge unsigned number that gives a different remainder on division than the small negative difference would. When you wrap, you are effectively adding 2<sup>32</sup>. 2<sup>32</sup> mod 65521 is 225, or `0xe1`, which is why you're seeing that difference in `b`. It's much more likely to wrap on the `b` calculation, but it can happen for `a` as well, if `a` happens to be very small at that step.

Per the comment by @samgak, you also have to worry about the definition of the % operator in different languages for signed values. So the solution that works across different conventions would be to make the values positive by adding as many `MOD`s as necessary, before doing the `% MOD`. For `a`, just add `MOD`. For `b`, add `(1 + n * leave / MOD) * MOD`.

Take care to make sure that the intermediate values don't overflow. The code in go can give erroneous results if `n*leave` is large enough to wrap the integer type being used.

Comment: You also need to take the different handling of negative modulo dividends between python and go into account. https://play.golang.org/p/R87XWewRPY (ignores the n*leave overflow)

Comment: "The code in both languages can give erroneous results if n*leave is large enough to wrap the integer type being used." - Python uses arbitrary-precision integers, so overflow isn't a problem in Python.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. Fixed that.

Comment: Wow an answer from the author of the checksum himself! Thank you very much for your clear explanation.

Comment: In order to make sure that `n*leave` does not wrap, I guess I can replace it with `n*leave % MOD == n%MOD*leave`, which is the same as doing `n%=MOD` prior to the whole operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know go, but here are some possibilities:

```
b := adler >> 16 change to b := (adler >> 16) & 0xffff

b = (b - n*leave - 1 + a) % MOD ... what happens if expression in () is negative?

return b<<16 | a ... check operator precedence; (b<<16)|a or b<<(16|a) ?

32-bit machine or 64-bit?
```